# adb cmd to disable touch panel

Tags: android, adb

Looking for an ADB cmd to disable touchpanel so that while running appium script, External Human Touch events donot disturb the running activity.

> Device_Type: Rooted
>
> Build: USER_DEBUG_BUILD